# Symmetric and Skew Symmetric Orthogonal Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $R$ is the subspace of n x n symmetric matrices, and $S$ is the subspace of n x n skew symmetric matrices, how do we show that $S^{\perp} \subseteq R$ with respect to the inner product $<x,y> = Tr(x^{T}y)$?

I can show that $R \subseteq S^{\perp}$, which relies on the fact that one can show $Tr(rs) = 0$ for any $r\in R$ and $s\in S$. I dont really see, formally, how this implies the direction above (that $S^{\perp} \subseteq R$, i.e. that $x\in S^{\perp} \implies x \in R$)? How does one prove $S^{\perp} \subseteq R$ formally?

Comment: Can you compute the dimensions of the subspaces ?

Comment: Yes, the dimensions of $R$ and $S$ are n(n+1)/2 and n(n-1)/2 respectively. Thus, the sum of the dimensions is exactly $n^2$. Is this, along with <r,s>=0, enough then? I also see that each matrix can be broken down as the sum of  a symmetric and skew symmetric matrix -- i think these are all the pieces, but I dont see how they fit together for the formal proof.

Comment: Yes, since the dimensions sum up, $S^\perp$ has the same dimension as $R$, hence $R\subseteq S^\perp$ implies $R=S^\perp$.

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that if $\operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)=0$ for all $B\in S$, then $A=A^T$. For this, they key is to write $A=A_1+A_2$, with $A_1$ symmetric and $A_2$ skew-symmetric. This is simply
$$
A=\frac{A+A^T}2+\frac{A-A^T}2. 
$$
Now
$$
0=\operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)=\operatorname{Tr}(A_1^TB)+\operatorname{Tr}(A_2^TB)=\operatorname{Tr}(A_2^TB). 
$$
And we are free to choose $B$, so in particular we may use $B=A_2$. Thus 
$$
0=\operatorname{Tr}(A_2^TA_2), 
$$
implying that $A_2=0$. Then $A=A^T$.